# Order Dell HDD's from Multiple Batches

Tags: dell

is it possible (has anyone ever done this) to get Dell to ship servers with HDD's from multiple batches to better protect against simultaneous failure? My Dell AE is not very helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be a party pooper, and no offense intended but, I hate to see these types of questions.

When you buy RAM do you buy each stick from a different batch? Do you buy tires for your car from different batches? Do your fast food french fries have to each come from a different potato?

I know I'm being a bit extreme but my point is this: buy the drives, don't worry about whether or not they're from the same batch and get on with your life. You probably have the same statistical chance of having multiple drives fail from different batches as you do with drives from the same batch.

I've purchased more servers from Dell than I can remember, have never requested or cared whether the drives came from the same batch or not, and have had probably 2 drive failures in 5 years, none simultaneous.

If you can point me to any real world studies that show that there's a higher incidence of multiple drive failures of drives sourced from the same lot, I'd love to see them.

Again, no offense intended.

Comment: No problem, here is a real world study: Google conducted an extensive study which concluded that same-batch harddrives have a much higher probability of failure. You can find it here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flabs.google.com%2Fpapers%2Fdisk_failures.pdf&ei=P6oHTa-nKpOosQP-rNSzDg&usg=AFQjCNGQnQZT4n9wJDyYMmOnmVqfnx1udw

Comment: OK, it's going to take me a while to read that, but thanks.

Comment: To make it easier, here is a quote: "Failure rates are known to be highly correlated with drive
models, manufacturers and vintages [18]. Our results do
not contradict this fact. For example, Figure 2 changes
signiﬁcantly when we normalize failure rates per each
drive model."

Comment: Well I'm reading it and so far I don't see any mention of same-source\same-batch disk drives in this study.

Comment: @joequerty: I believe @AX1 is assuming the word "vintage" used in this study (and the one cited by reference #18 of the study) roughly correlates to "batch". I'm not sure if that is correct or not though.

Comment: @MattB: I read vintage to mean "age" and I don't see how that can correlate to "batch". They may be the same age, but from different batches, plants, etc... Interesting study though.

Comment: Unlike RAM, french fries, and to an extent, tires, one hard drive failing has a very different impact from more than one hard drive failing. Even if the jury's out about whether a single batch is significantly more likely to have multiple failures, I disagree with so casually dismissing the relevance

Comment: Here's another study (http://www2.cs.uh.edu/~paris/MYPAPERS/StorageSS06.pdf) which I found among a discussion here: http://lwn.net/Articles/237924/.  Less usefully, an anecdote: http://superuser.com/questions/11607/looking-for-an-actual-experience-of-raid-5-2-drive-failure